# Haml: Control whitespace around text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In my Rails template, I'd like to accomplish final HTML to this effect using HAML:

```
I will first <a href="http://example.com">link somewhere</a>, then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met
```

The template that comes close:

```
I will first
= link_to 'link somewhere', 'http://example.com'
- if @condition
  , then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met
```

You may, however, note that this produces a space between the link and the comma. Is there any practical way to avoid this whitespace? I know there's syntax to remove whitespace around tags, but can this same syntax be applied to just text? I really don't like the solution of extra markup to accomplish this.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

A better way to do this has been introduced via Haml's helpers:

#### [surround](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#surround)

```
= surround '(', ')' do
  %a{:href => "food"} chicken
```

Produces:

```
(<a href='food'>chicken</a>)
```

#### [succeed](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#succeed):

```
click
= succeed '.' do
  %a{:href=>"thing"} here
```

Produces:

```
click
<a href='thing'>here</a>.
```

#### [precede](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#precede):

```
= precede '*' do
  %span.small Not really
```

Produces:

```
*<span class='small'>Not really</span>
```

#### To answer the original question:

```
I will first
= succeed ',' do
  = link_to 'link somewhere', 'http://example.com'
- if @condition
  then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met
```

Produces:

```
I will first
<a href="http://example.com">link somewhere</a>,
then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met
```

Comment: Nice timing, I just found out about these by reading Haml's source.  Apparently they've been around for a while.

Odd that they don't document them in the main reference page...

Comment: Can you expand your answer and show to express the OP's example using these helpers (presumably `succeed` specifically)? To me it still seems non-obvious and a little ugly: https://gist.github.com/1665374

Comment: I feel like I am missing something (while looking on upvotes count), but the *succeed* variant isn't equivalent to the original one, because trailing comma will be rendered even if `@condition == false`, which is more ugly than space before this comma.

Comment: I managed to get the correct result by using precede, rather than succeed. Cheers!

Answer (score 40):

You can also do this using Haml's "trim whitespace" modifier. Inserting `>` after a Haml declaration will prevent whitespace from being added around it:

```
I will first
%a{:href => 'http://example.com'}> link somewhere
- if @condition
  , then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met
```

produces:

```
I will first<a href='http://example.com'>link somewhere</a>, then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met
```

However, as you can see, the `>` modifier also strips the whitespace in front of the link, removing the desired space between the words and the link. I haven't figured a pretty way around this yet, except to add `&nbsp;` to the end of "I will first", like so:

```
I will first&nbsp;
%a{:href => 'http://example.com'}> link somewhere
- if @condition
  , then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met
```

Which finally produces the desired output without lots of hard-to-read interpolation:

```
I will first&nbsp;<span><a href="http://example.com">link somewhere</a></span>, then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I got this from the Haml cheat sheet, which is very helpful: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/haml/

Comment: It works with tags but not expressions; in your example you've changed his expression to a tag. I have the same issue and unfortunately this is not a solution.

Comment: I would remark that `&nbsp;` have a special meaning to it, it's not an ordinary whitespace - it's non-breaking whitespace, which means that during word-wrapping browser would do everything to keep words tied with `&nbsp;` together and this is not always what you want.

Comment: In addition to Andrew's comment, use `&#032;` instead of `&nbsp;` for just a plain whitespace.

Answer (score 12):

Alright, here's the solution I'm settling on:

### Helper

```
def one_line(&block)
  haml_concat capture_haml(&block).gsub("\n", '').gsub('\\n', "\n")
end
```

### View

```
I will first
- one_line do
  = link_to 'link somewhere', 'http://example.com'
  - if @condition
    , then render this half of the sentence
    \\n
    if a condition is met
```

That way, whitespace is excluded by default, but I can still explicitly include it with a "\n" line. (It needs the double-backslash because otherwise HAML interprets it as an actual newline.) Let me know if there's a better option out there!

Comment: Note to world: I eventually wised up and moved these to helpers :P

Comment: Another note to world: these days, I use Groxx's solution :)

Comment: This is very helpful when it comes to haml that generates a text file! In my case I had one line where part of it was decided by an "if", which I couldn't fix with mysamillidea's solution because it doesn't get rid of newlines, it just moves the comma before the newline. (Though I agree that for the answer to the original question mysmallidea's is the best.)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the 'aligator syntax' of HAML

> Whitespace Removal: > and <
>
> and < give you more control over the whitespace near a tag. > will remove all whitespace surrounding a tag, while < will remove all whitespace immediately within a tag. You can think of them as alligators eating the whitespace: > faces out of the tag and eats the whitespace on the outside, and < faces into the tag and eats the whitespace on the inside. They’re placed at the end of a tag definition, after class, id, and attribute declarations but before / or =.

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_

Answer (score 5):

Once approach I've taken to this sort of thing is to use string interpolation:

```
I will first #{link_to 'Link somewhere'}#{', then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met' if condition}
```

I don't like the look of the literal string in the interpolation, but I've used it with previously declared strings or dynamically generated strings before.

Comment: Mhm. That's my general approach to things like that, but I had never thought of using the conditional in there. It's a shame that the actual template I was using turned out to be a bit more complex than just a second half of a sentence... but that's definitely worth remembering - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this to keep the leading space:

```
%a{:href => 'http://example.com'}>= ' link somewhere'
```

The space is in the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Although not well documented, this is cleanly achieved using HAML whitespace preservation (>) combined with an ASCII space (& #32;), and not with helpers:

```
%a{:href=>'/home'}> Home link
,&#32; 
%a{:href=>'/page'} Next link
```

This will produce what you want:

```
<a href='/home'>Anchor text</a>,&#32;
<a href='/page'>More text</a>
```

But I agree, HAML needs to come up with a better way of doing this, as it does add unnecessary ASCII characters to the page (but it's still more efficient than using helpers).

Answer (score 1):

There's the angle bracket "whitespace munching" syntax, otherwise write a helper method for it.

Comment: How exactly would a helper for that work? Meh, I'll see what I can come up with...

Comment: As for whitespace munching, I can't work out how to make that syntax work if it's not on some sort of tag definition. Am I just doing it wrong, or does that syntax not work without a tag?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem and found this so I thought I would post another solution which doesn't require a helper method.  Use Ruby interpolation #{} to wrap the link and if statements:

```
I will first 
#{link_to 'link somewhere', 'http://example.com'}#{if true : ", then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met" end}
```

This works in 3.0.18, it may also work in earlier releases.

Comment: Granted, Haml isn't designed for content. This isn't content that we're talking about there, though. It's a template. The author of that blog post is referring to things like writing a full static webpage in Haml, which isn't what I'm doing. The code snippet I provided is pretty much the full `.haml` file — the fact that it includes a link and a comma doesn't really indicate anything either way.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I've edited my answer, leaving the solution to stand on its own.

Comment: While this may work I think it makes for hard to read markup. Instead just use the HAML whitespace modifiers < and > as other people have mentioned which keeps your HAML clean and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option that I've used in the past:

```
- if @condition
  %span> , then some more text after the link.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also always do:

```
= link_to url_path do 
  = ["part_1", "part_2"].join(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I got working is:

```
I will first
= link_to 'link somewhere', 'http://example.com'
- if @condition
  = ", then render this half of the sentence if a condition is met"
```

You can use `=`, though `=` is used to output the result of Rails code, but here it will server the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The [preserve](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#preserve-instance_method) function worked for me

`.white-space-pre= preserve "TEXT"`