# HAML: remove white space after "link_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

The following code leaves a white space in HTML:

```
= link_to "Login", "#"
```

Normally, HAML allows to remove it by putting ">" at the end of the line, for example:

```
%input#query{:type => "text", :value => "Search"}>
```

However, that seems to be impossible, when Rails code is inserted.

How do I fix this?

Comment: This answer is much, much better:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311428/haml-control-whitespace-around-text

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about this?

```
%span>= link_to "Login", "#"
```

It adds an extra span around the link, but those are pretty harmless.

I find haml can have a bit of a problem with some of these corner cases :(

Answer (score 25):

The solution with span is not ideal as it adds an unnecessary html tag that will require processing, if you want to avoid the `<span>` you should use HAML's `succeed`:

```
= succeed "," do
  = link_to "Login", "#"
```

which will result in the following HTML being rendered:

```
Login,
```

rather than

```
Login ,
```

Note that if you want to achieve the following result:

```
Login,Profile
```

i.e. no whitespace whatsoever between the comma and two links you should do the following:

```
= succeed link_to "Profile", '#' do
  = succeed "," do
    = link_to "Login", '#'
```

which gets pretty tedious

Comment: What a gem. This the "right" way to do it. Documentation: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#succeed-instance_method

Comment: There is also `precede` which doesn't require you to turn the order around.
http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#precede-instance_method

Answer (score 8):

You could but the `>` on the following line.

```
= link_to "Login", "#"
#something_else>
```

Comment: Thanks, %span{:style => "display:none;"}> seems to work fine, but using it multiple times is such a terrible solution... I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this thread I find I most need to remove whitespace most when a link is at the end of a sentence.

I'll usually use:

`= link_to("Login", '#) + '. '`

which results in:

`<a href="#">Login</a>.`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another poor alternative solution for removing spaces between several rails lines using the :ruby filter:

```
:ruby
             haml_io.write f.hidden_field('params_ar[][units]', value: 'time')
             haml_io.write f.text_field("params_ar[][minutes]", value:pars[param_num][:minutes],class:'time-input minutes', placeholder:'mm')
             haml_io.write ':'
             haml_io.write f.text_field("params_ar[][seconds]", value:pars[param_num][:seconds],class:'time-input seconds' ,placeholder:'ss')
```