# ruby rails delete space after link_to without HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I am programming an app with Ruby on Rails and, in some views, I would like to get rid of the automatic whitespace triggered by the 'link_to' helper.

```eruby
<%= link_to liker.first_name.capitalize, user_path(liker) %>
   <!-- Example of link with a user's firstname (who liked a given content), redirecting to it's user profile -->
```

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680099/haml-remove-white-space-after-link-to), which talks about using HAML (that I do not use). Isn't it possible to delete this tiny whitespace only using Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Are you getting extra white space in link text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always get a whitespace between inline html elements if you put them in different lines in your html document. For example

```
<span>foo</span>
<span>bar</span>
```

would render as "foo bar" on the page. But if you write that html elements next to each other in one line, without a whitespace in between

```
<span>foo</span><span>bar</span>
```

it would render as "foobar".

That said: Just write the `link_to` into the same line with the text that should not be separated with a whitespace:

```
foo<%= link_to 'bar', '#' %>baz
```

Would look like "foo[bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226017/ruby-rails-delete-space-after-link-to-without-haml)baz" without any whitespace

Answer (score 0):

As Akshay said you can use `.strip` or `.strip!` to remove leading and trailing whitespace.But if you want to remove all whitespace use some tricky hack like `.gsub(/\s+/, "")` or `.gsub(" ","")`.

```
<%= link_to liker.first_name.capitalize.to_s.gsub(/\s+/, ""), user_path(liker) %>
```

Comment: My 'first_name' attribute was already cleaned in terms of whitespaces (before saving in the DB). The suggestion by @spickermann made the job. Thanks in any case!