# Question about removing whitespace in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I know how to remove whitespace in HAML.

```
%img<
%img<
%img
```

But how do I get the same effect if I use ruby code?

```
= image_tag
= image_tag
```

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haml: Control whitespace around text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311428/haml-control-whitespace-around-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What not just do this?

```
 = image_tag + image_tag
```

Not ideal, but you could also wrap in a span tag in order to use `>`

```
 %span>= image_tag
 %span>= image_tag
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (for example, text after image) can help interpolation:

```
  #{image_tag 'image.png'}text
```