# Symbols near HAML expressions

Tags: haml

In HAML I often want to use a tag with punctuation following immediately after the tag. For example, I might want to put something in bold but have a closing bracket. The formatting would look like this: (Example sentence with **bold text**.)

Note that the 'bold text' is in bold but the period and closing bracket '.)' are not.

The obvious HAML is like this:

```
(Example sentence with
%span.important bold text
\.)
```

but this causes an extra space between 'bold text' and '.)'. Here's one way of doing it instead:

```
(Example sentence with
%span.important bold text
%span>\.)
```

Where enclosing the '.)' in a span with `>` makes the space disappear. However, this requires an unnecessary span.

**Is there any way of getting the desired output, without the extra span?**

Comment: The haml faq covers pretty much this exact question: http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-punctuation - the answer is basically the same as Daves below: inline html or a filter.

Comment: I've adjusted the example to make it clearer, with thanks to @Dave.

Comment: http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/ this might help you somehow :) it just supports matt and Dave's assertion that you could just use inline/markdown for inline tags..because haml is for layout

Comment: There are three HAML helpers (surround, precede, and succeed) that address this specifically. Read [Haml: Control whitespace around text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311428/haml-control-whitespace-around-text) or read "Helper Methods" in the [HAML documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That initial code snippet shouldn't work in HAML at all:

```
(Example sentence with
%b bold text
.)
```

The third line would result in an `Illegal element: classes and ids must have values` error. It should be:

```
(Example sentence with
%b bold text
\.)
```

However, that just fixes the code error. It still displays the way you're complaining about. I only know of two ways to address it:

1. Just use inline HTML tags in your HAML file: `(Example sentence with <b>bold text</b>.)`
2. Install **maruku** (or another markdown gem) and do the following:

> ```
> :markdown  
>   (Example sentence with **bold text**.)
> ```

Comment: Definitely right about the `\.` (thanks). However, not quite a complete solution for me as `%b` is only an example and I want to handle tags in general, including custom tags.