# punctuation after a link in ruby haml

Tags: ruby, haml

I have this code:

```
%p
   A debtor with the court's approval can hire attorneys via
   %a{:id=>"proc",:href=>'/codes#rule327'}Section 327.
```

That renders:

A debtor with the court's approval can hire attorneys via **Section 327.**

I know this is extremely picky, but I do not want the period bolded. When I try:

```
%p
   A debtor with the court's approval can hire attorneys via
   %a{:id=>"proc",:href=>'/codes#rule327'}Section 327
   \.
```

It yields:

A debtor with the court's approval can hire attorneys via **Section 327** .

I would like to know how do I get:

A debtor with the court's approval can hire attorneys via **Section 327**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the outer "space eater" (>) after the tag definition:

```
%p
  A debtor with the court's approval can hire attorneys via
  %a{:id=>"proc",:href=>'/codes#rule327'}>Section 327
  .
```

[Manual reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_)

Comment: sweet, didn't know that thanks! also for anyone else reading i made a slight edit, there needs to be a backspace in front of the period, otherwise the haml compiler will think thats a class definition.

Comment: Other note: mthaml PHP library allows the dot pass.

Comment: @shicholas Note that this also removes space _before_ the tag as well, so this still isn’t exactly what you want. See what the [Haml FAQ has to say about this](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-punctuation).

Comment: @shicholas I'm having the same problem, but inserting a backspace causes the compiler to complain about indentation. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "inserting a backspace" can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 39):

HAML has helper methods specifically designed to "manipulate whitespace in a more precise fashion than what the whitespace removal methods allow."

There are three methods: surround, precede, and succeed, which provide better whitespace control. In your case, you can use the succeed helper like this to append the period after the link:

```
%p
  A debtor with the court's approval can hire attorneys via
  = succeed "." do
    %a{:id=>"proc",:href=>'/codes#rule327'}Section 327
```

See the [HAML documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html) under "Helper Methods".

Comment: Also read: [Haml: Control whitespace around text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311428/haml-control-whitespace-around-text)

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Important to note that the tag content ("Section 327") is on the same line as the tag definition. If it is nested on the following line, there will be the space.