# Removing whitespace only after closing tag in HAML

Tags: haml

I have a list of items separated by commas.  It looks like this:

> With a user-centric, iterative, and pragmatic approach

"User-centric" is wrapped in a span.highlight.

%span.highlight>user-centric removes the whitespace between the content and the comma as expected but it also removes the whitespace between 'a' and 'user-centric.'

> With auser-centric, iterative . . .

What's the cleanest way to get rid of the trailing whitespace?

Comment: Can you post code snippet?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6283768/135673